# How to draw a 3-dimensional sphere whose Head is Image3D?

Tags: list-manipulation, image3d

In 2 dimensions, I can do like this to draw my image:

```
Image[Graphics[{Circle[]}]]
```

But in 3 dimensions, this method will give an error information:

[image]

So I try another **array method**:

```
Image[Thinning[Unitize[EntropyFilter[ArrayPad[DiskMatrix[{10, 10}], 1], 1]]]]
```

[image]

This is good method in 2 dimensions. But the function `Thinning` cannot be used in 3 dimensions. So I don't know how to draw a 3D sphere still.

---

#### Update:

It seem the

```
EdgeDetect[Image3D[ArrayPad[DiskMatrix[{40, 40, 40}], 1]]]
```

[image]

is close to what I want.But this method is costing memory very much and the surface'sthickness seem to be not very uniform.

Comment: It seems that just `Image3D[DiskMatrix[{100, 100, 100}]]` works, but I'm curious why the interplay between `Image` and `Graphics` works, while the interplay between `Image3D` and `Graphics3D` does not....

Comment: @JoshBishop 3-dimension sphere is a surface of ball but not solid

Comment: is there a reason you need a solid in image form?

Comment: Can someone please write and explain the code for the above 3-sphere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we are in `11.2`,the `RegionImage` can help us to implement it

```
RegionImage[Sphere[]]
```

[image]

It is what I want exactly.

Comment: Those Moiré patterns are attractive, or distracting, depending on your point of view.

Comment: @J.M. I wonder where they come from. It'd be interesting to know if it's an issue of meshing or rendering.